# Sending friend request in facebook using mail id

Tags: android, facebook

i am integrating the facebook to my android application, here i need to send friend request by using mail ID which has been registered as linkedin done through their api calls.

i researched more and spent lot of time on this i could not get any solutions, so i request you guys to provide me any sample codes or any solution for this.

Thanking you

Comment: I do not think that you can send friend requests or send messages using the api anymore. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

There's the [Friends Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/) but I can't say if it works well in android (using the [Dialogs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/dialog/)) but you should be able to open it in a webview.

Notice the restriction/warning on the documentation:

> This feature is intended to help users become friends on Facebook with
>   people that they are connected to in real life. You should not use
>   this feature to encourage users to friend other users that they are
>   not connected to in real life. If your app is found to be encouraging
>   this behavior, your usage of this feature may be disabled.

With that said, you can't use `email` as an identifier, the entire facebook api (graph and fql) works with either the user id or username.
If you check the [User fql table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) you'll see that only indexable fields are `uid`, `username` and `name`.